# GoogleMaps api vs https://maps.google.com/

Tags: android, google-maps

I have next problem:i start to develope an app with google maps api.And at this point i find that my map  display not all public places like it is in  ://maps.google.com/.You can see difference in next 2 screens,GoogleMaps Screen is from google maps official website.Genymotion is from my app.

[GoogleMaps Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxLrC.png) ;
[Genymotion(my app) screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdwc1.png)

How can i display all places in my app like in GoogleMaps Screen.I need to work with other api or is there some tehnologie to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Googles Places Api:
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/

Comment: ok ,if i use this api this would aloud me to display all places by types?i mean that i want it to desplay when app is starting